# jquery doesn't recognize form tag as Form, dont able to serialize

Tags: jquery, forms

i append some forms to a div container, the form very depending of the option selected, so i dont have any id related, because can be more than one,

so what i do is just

```
$('.item').each(function(index,element){

    var form= $(element).find('form');
    var formFields = form.serialize();

    console.debug("FORM: "+ formFields);

    //--- do something with those fields
});
```

But is always empty , so i try to change this line

```
var formFields = getFormData(form);
```

and added this function

```
function getFormData($form){
    var indexed_array = {};

    var selectors = "input,select";

    $form.find(selectors).each(function(i,e){

        var type    = $(e).attr('type');
        var name    = $(e).attr('name');
        indexed_array[name] = value;

    });

    $form.find('textarea').each(function(i,e){
        var name  = $(e).attr('name');
        var value = $(e).html();
        indexed_array[name] = value;
    });


    return indexed_array;
}
```

it worked but the problem it takes checkbox or radiobutton that aren't checked

so i try to change the selector for this options

```
var selectors = ":input"; //didnt work
var selectors = "input[type=text],input:checked,select"; //didnt work
var selectors = "input[type=text],input[type=checkbox]:checked,input[type=radio]:checked,select"; //didnt work
```

those selector tries, didnt retrive me anything , is like the jquery doesnt reconize the form as form, and didnt detect even if a input is selected , checked or not , any suggestion?

HTML , remember can be more than one of these

```
<div class="column-2 item">
    <div class="widget-item">
        <span>12 Months Traffic Trend Unique Visits </span>
        <div class="widget-option">        
            <form>    
            <div class="form-item">   
                <div class="form-label">Compare With Last Year</div>
                <div class="form-element"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="compareLastYear"></div>
             </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us some html as well.

Comment: It's better if you include also the HTML of your `<form>` itself

Comment: Can you show your HTML, or an example of its structure please?

Comment: check form id may be you have same id for more than one form..

Answer (score 0):

> so i dont have any id related, because can be more than one,

Then use a class to allow multiple instances:

```
<form class='formClass'>
```

Then you can do

```
$('.formClass').each(function(k,v){

    var form = v; // this is the form
    var fields = $(v).serialize();
});
```

SEE THIS [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VV6Dm/)